# Mootools mousewheel event, and adding an onComplete

Tags: javascript, mootools, scroll

I'm using the following class along with Mootools to create custom scrolling areas on a site. It includes a mousewheel event. I need to be able to fire an onComplete once the scroller comes to a stop after using the mousewheel. So say you swipe the mousewheel to scroll, I need to fire an oncomplete once the scrolling content comes to a stop.

Suggestions?

```
var ScrollBar = new Class({

    Implements: [Events, Options],

    options: {
        wheel: (Browser.safari5) ? 1 : 20
    },

    initialize: function(main, options) {

        this.setOptions(options);

        this.dragging = false;
        this.inside = false;

        this.main = $(main);
        this.content = this.main.getFirst();

        this.vScrollbar = new Element('div', {
            'class': 'scrollbar'
        }).inject(this.content, 'after');

        this.vTrack = new Element('div', {
            'class': 'track'
        }).inject(this.vScrollbar);

        this.vThumb = new Element('div', {
            'class': 'handle'
        }).inject(this.vTrack);

        this.bound = {
            'vStart': this.vStart.bind(this),
            'end': this.end.bind(this),
            'vDrag': this.vDrag.bind(this),
            'wheel': this.wheel.bind(this),
            'vPage': this.vPage.bind(this)
        };
        // set scrollarea mousein/out hide of scrollbar
        this.vScrollbar.set('tween', {
            duration: 200,
            transition: 'cubic:out'
        });
        this.main.addEvent('mouseenter', function(event){
            this.inside = true;
            this.vScrollbar.get('tween').cancel();
            this.vScrollbar.tween('width', 12);
        }.bind(this));
        this.main.addEvent('mouseleave', function(event){
            this.inside = false;
            if (!this.dragging) {
                this.vScrollbar.get('tween').cancel();
                this.vScrollbar.tween('width', 0);
            }
        }.bind(this));

        this.vPosition = {};
        this.vMouse = {};
        this.update();
        this.attach();

        this.scrollContent = new Fx.Scroll(this.content, {
            duration: 500,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Cubic.easeOut,
            onComplete: function(){
                Blinds.updateImages();
            }
        });
        this.scrollThumb = new Fx.Morph(this.vThumb, {
            duration: 500,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Cubic.easeOut
        });
    },

    update: function() {

        var panel_id = (this.content.getFirst()) ? this.content.getFirst().get('id') : '';

        if ((this.content.scrollHeight <= this.main.offsetHeight) || panel_id === 'random-doodle' || (this.content.getFirst() && this.content.getFirst().hasClass('collapsed'))) {
            this.main.addClass('noscroll');
            return false;
        }
        else { this.main.removeClass('noscroll'); }

        this.vContentSize = this.content.offsetHeight;
        this.vContentScrollSize = this.content.scrollHeight;
        this.vTrackSize = this.vTrack.offsetHeight;

        this.vContentRatio = this.vContentSize / this.vContentScrollSize;

        this.vThumbSize = 200;
        this.vThumb.setStyle('height', this.vThumbSize);

        this.vScrollRatio = this.vContentScrollSize / (this.vTrackSize - this.vThumbSize) - this.vContentRatio * (this.vContentScrollSize / (this.vTrackSize - this.vThumbSize));

        this.vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll();
        this.vUpdateContentFromThumbPosition();

    },

    vUpdateContentFromThumbPosition: function() {
        this.content.scrollTop = this.vPosition.now * this.vScrollRatio;
    },

    vUpdateContentFromThumbPosition2: function() {
        var pos = this.vPosition.now * this.vScrollRatio;
        this.scrollContent.start(0, pos);
    },

    vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll: function() {
        this.vPosition.now = (this.content.scrollTop / this.vScrollRatio).limit(0, (this.vTrackSize - this.vThumbSize));
        this.vThumb.setStyle('top', this.vPosition.now);
    },

    vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll2: function(pos) {
        this.vPosition.now = (this.content.scrollTopNew / this.vScrollRatio).limit(0, (this.vTrackSize - this.vThumbSize));           
        this.scrollThumb.start({
            'top': this.vPosition.now       
        });
    },

    attach: function() {
        if (this.options.wheel) { this.content.addEvent('mousewheel', this.bound.wheel); }
        this.vThumb.addEvent('mousedown', this.bound.vStart);
        this.vTrack.addEvent('mouseup', this.bound.vPage);
    },

    wheel: function(event) {
        this.content.scrollTop -= event.wheel * this.options.wheel;
        this.vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll();
        event.stop();
    },

    scrollTo: function(pos){
        myInstance = this;
        this.content.scrollTopNew = pos;
        this.scrollContent.start(0, this.content.scrollTopNew);
        myInstance.vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll2(pos);
    },

    vPage: function(event) {
        // if scrolling up
        if (event.page.y > this.vThumb.getPosition().y) {
            myInstance = this;
            this.content.scrollTopNew = this.content.scrollTop.toInt() + this.content.offsetHeight.toInt();
            this.scrollContent.start(0, this.content.scrollTopNew);
        }
        // if scrolling down
        else {
            myInstance = this;    
            this.content.scrollTopNew = this.content.scrollTop.toInt() - this.content.offsetHeight.toInt();    
            this.scrollContent.start(0, this.content.scrollTopNew);       
        }
        myInstance.vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll2(event.page.y);
        event.stop();
    },

    vStart: function(event) {
        this.dragging = true;
        this.vMouse.start = event.page.y;
        this.vPosition.start = this.vThumb.getStyle('top').toInt();
        document.addEvent('mousemove', this.bound.vDrag);
        document.addEvent('mouseup', this.bound.end);
        this.vThumb.addEvent('mouseup', this.bound.end);
        event.stop();
    },

    end: function(event) {
        this.dragging = false;
        if (!this.inside) {
            this.vScrollbar.get('tween').cancel();
            this.vScrollbar.tween('width', 0);
        }
        document.removeEvent('mousemove', this.bound.vDrag);
        document.removeEvent('mouseup', this.bound.end);
        this.vThumb.removeEvent('mouseup', this.bound.end);

        Blinds.updateImages();

        event.stop();
    },

    vDrag: function(event) {
        this.vMouse.now = event.page.y;
        this.vPosition.now = (this.vPosition.start + (this.vMouse.now - this.vMouse.start)).limit(0, (this.vTrackSize - this.vThumbSize));
        this.vUpdateContentFromThumbPosition();
        this.vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll();
        event.stop();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your wheel function to reset a [delayed function timer](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function%3adelay) (after clearing any previous timers that might still exist).  To have the 'autoComplete' fired 1000ms after the *last* wheel event, try something like this:

```
wheel: function(event) {
    this.content.scrollTop -= event.wheel * this.options.wheel;
    this.vUpdateThumbFromContentScroll();

    // clear the timer from previous wheel events, if it still exists
    if(this.timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    this.timer = function() {this.fireEvent('autoComplete');}.delay(1000, this);

    event.stop();
},
```

Comment: Should I change `if (timer)` to `if (this.timer)`?

Comment: Also, where would I add the `autoComplete` event?

Comment: Yup, `this.timer` is what you need.

Comment: My apologies.  I don't know what `autoComplete` is, except that you referred to it in your original question.  Since you used the word 'fire', I assumed you were referring to MooTools' Class Event functionality: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class.Extras#Events   .. However, the contents of the function being `delay`d are up to you :)

Comment: (What I mean is, rather than `this.fireEvent('autoComplete');`, you could write whatever you want, i.e. `this.doneMouseWheeling();`

Comment: I think one of the best things about mootools is the ability to do both - run a method AND fire an event whenever something 'awesome' happens. the events allow your instances to override or act upon various things that have happened and gives you increased flexibility / scalability. check this blog post http://ryanflorence.com/11-tips-for-creating-great-mootools-plugins/ on best practices in mootools class creation, it makes sense! :)